# How can I get a VC++ Form app to detect a radio button selection?

Tags: c++, forms, button, if-statement, statements

So I'm a novice with C++ Forms. I'm in VC++2010 Express. I decided to start learning how to make form apps and not just console apps. So I wanted to make one of my console apps into a form app.

So I have this code here:

```
PlaySound("Millionaire/£100Play.wav",NULL,SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT);    
            question -> Text = "Let's Play!"; 
            question -> Text = "question";
            A -> Text = "Answer A";
            B -> Text = "Answer B";
            C -> Text = "Answer C";
            D -> Text = "Answer D";

            if (BN_CLICKED && AButton->Checked ) //This is me testing it out, more likely than not wrong
            {
                PlaySound("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£100correct.wav",NULL,SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT);     
                A -> BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;              
                questionsAway -> Text = "Away: 14";
                moneyWon -> Text = "£100";
                indicator -> BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
                moneyWorth -> Text = "£200";
                moneyLost -> Text = "£100";
                info -> Text = "Enter text relating the answer to the question or general facts.";
            }

            else
            {
                PlaySound("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£100and£64000lose.wav",NULL,SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT);
                indicator -> BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
            }    
        }
```

So what this does is display some text in text boxes along with some sounds. Now the main problem here is the if and else statements. I have radio buttons for the user to select, each one corresponding to answer A, B, C or D. Now what happens here is instead of the program waiting for input, it immediately goes right to the else statement on startup as A isn't selected and treats the answer as incorrect. My question is, how can I get the program to wait for input OR detect when an button is selected?

Comment: When a button is clicked, or when a radio button changes selection, or in general, when something happens, there are events that fire up. You need to catch those events. check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page for a description of the event that you want to handle, and some examples.

Comment: Ok, but how could I incorporate this into my if/else statements? What would the code look like?

Comment: You need to create an event handler for `onclick` for that button. In that event handler, you check to see if the checked item is the correct one. You might also need to use the `oncheckedchange` event handler to enable the button if you want the user to select at least one of the radio buttons (if none is selected by default at the start).

Comment: Alright, I've gotcha. Thanks for the help!